# Trouble accessing data from a joined sql table in express

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I'm using express and postgreSQL to create an api that shows restaurant ratings, reviews and cuisine in given areas.  So far I have managed to create routes and controllers that will display the sql tables in postman.

However my issue occurs when trying to harness data from joined tables in sql.  I know how to specify the data I want in sql using JOIN, but my problem is once I have that data how do I take data from the joined table and make the api send a response with the cherrypicked data.  Here are my tables:

[image: sql tables]

the first table is the areas table, the second table the restaurants table.  They both share an area_id which i used in the third table which is the joined table.  It is the name of the city in the joined table(bottom right) that I particularly want access to...

Here is my express controller dealing with the request to get all restaurants of a particular area_id:

```
const getRestaurantsByAreaId = (req, res, next) => {
  db.many(
    "SELECT * FROM restaurants JOIN areas ON areas.area_id = restaurants.area_id WHERE areas.area_id = $<area_id>",
    {
      area_id: req.params.area_id
    }
  )
    .then(restaurants => {
      res.status(200).send({
        area_id: req.params.area_id,
        name: '',
        total_restaurants: restaurants.length,
        restaurants
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

router endpoint:

```
areasRouter.get('/:area_id/restaurants', getRestaurantsByAreaId)
```

As you can see I have made the query to the sql db to create the joined table, however in the object that is sent as a response (after .then) I have the key of 'name' - here the value here needs to be 'manchester city centre' from the joined table... but I do not know how to do this after much trying..

In postman I make a request to see restaurants in area_id '1':  http://localhost:9090/api/areas/1/restaurants

Here is what is received client side from the above code..

[image: client side postman]

So everything is working apart from the last bit, getting that city name from the joined table.

Hopefully this isn't too much of a noob question, but I am a noob hehe.
Appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figures it out.  Pretty easy solution, don't know why I missed this...

name: restaurants[0].name